# Error in studio SQLiteException: json_each

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have json Array in my column and i want to extract json array as separate values I am using sqlite query

```
 SELECT
     json_extract(t2.value, '$.time') as time
 FROM
     json_each((SELECT column_name
                FROM tbl_name)) AS t2
```

My column looks like this

```
 [{"time":0,"value":0},{"time":2,"value":0},{"time":0,"value":0}]
```

It works fine in sqlite browser but I get an error in Android studio.

> SQLiteException: no such table: json_each (code 1):

Update: I am using room database and it works fine for other queries

Comment: I am usion room Database and it wokrs fine for other querries

Comment: Post your RoomDatabase class

Comment: there is nothing wrong with class , its in querry for json_each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_each` and `json_extract` would need [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html). It's not available on Android. You need to do your json mapping in code.

Comment: JSON1 extensions are available in Android via the [requery/sqlite-android](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) library, here's an example of it being added as a [helper](https://github.com/aartikov/flipper-database-bug/blob/master/app/src/main/java/me/aartikov/flipper_database_bug/App.kt) to a Room database